# Using a variable for a createDrawerNavigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am working on a simple React Native e-commerce app and i ran into a issue. I am trying to add the option to change the language, and it has worked so far with the Redux but now i need to dynamically change the sidebar menu and I cant because it is hardcoded as a prop.The code for the menu is this.

```
const ShopNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  { 
    Produktetee: ProductsNavigator,
    Rezervimet: OrdersNavigator,
    Postoni: AdminNavigator},
  {
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: MyColors.primary
    },
    contentComponent: props => {
      const {log_out} = useSelector(state =>  state.language)
   
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 50 }}>
          <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: "always", horizontal: "never" }}>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
            <Button
              title={log_out}
              color={MyColors.primary}
              onPress={() => {
                dispatch(authActions.logOut());
                // props.navigation.navigate("Auth");
              }}
            />
             <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
 <View style={{flex:1 , marginRight:10, marginTop: 5,}} >
            <Button
              title="English"
              type="outline"
            
              color={MyColors.primary}
              onPress={()=>{
                dispatch(index.selectLanguage(languages.english))
              }}
            />
            </View>
            <View style={{flex:1, marginTop: 5,}} >
            <Button
              title="Shqip"
              type="outline"
     
              color={MyColors.primary}
              onPress={()=>{
                dispatch(index.selectLanguage(languages.albanian))
              }}
            />
            </View>
 </View>
          </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
);
```

I am trying to use the hook, but I can't. If somebody could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: The setup that you are using with the `contentComponent` is from an old version of React Navigation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/drawer-navigator/  The current version uses a different syntax based on child components: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator  I would start by looking into that.  Perhaps updating your code will help.